# In python pandas,How to use outer join using where condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Table 1

```
S.No  BusNo Timings People
1     1234  3:05 pm  55
2     3456  3:30 pm  45
3     8945  3:45 pm  50

Table 2 
BusNo  Model
1234   Leyland
3456   Viking
```

Join this table using pandas for condition: busno model people count for  people between 50 and 55 and group by model

Expected Output:

Table3

```
S.No BusNo Timings People Model
1    1234  3:05 pm  55    Leyland
3    8945  3:45 pm  50    Nan
```

Comment: please post a sample df and expected output

Comment: Table 1 is dataframe1 and Table 2 is dataframe 2

Comment: please post your expected dataframe too

Comment: @pyd please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple merge on those two dataframes and do a simple condition check inside `loc` to get the desired output like shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['S.No'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['BusNo'] = [1234, 3456, 8945]
df['Timings'] = ['3:05 pm', '3:30 pm', '3:45 pm']
df['People'] = [55, 45, 50]

df_ = pd.DataFrame()

df_['BusNo'] = [1234, 8945]
df_['Model'] = ['Leyland', 'viking']


merged = pd.merge(df, df_, on='BusNo', how='outer')

merged.loc[(merged['People'] >= 50) & (merged['People'] <= 55), :]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [pd.Series.between](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html),

```
 df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='BusNo',how='outer')
 df.loc[df['People'].between(50,55,inclusive=True),:]
```

Comment: Thank You got the answer